# Projeto Java Web

Tags: java, jsf, servlet

Para programar Java Web, é necessário usar a extensão JavaServer Faces ou posso usar apenas páginas HTML com Servlet?

E qual a diferença de usar sem o JSF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Não é necessário o JSF para programar em Java Web**, ele é apenas um framework que te ajuda, simplificando seu trabalho.
O JSF costuma trazer também alguns componentes prontos que te ajudam a construir uma interface mais bonita sem tanta dificuldade.
Respondendo a sua pergunta: uma aplicação sem o uso do JSF precisará ser mais trabalhada em alguns detalhes, o que pode ser um pouco trabalhoso, ou necessitará da utilização de outros frameworks, enquanto uma aplicação com JSF economizará trabalho do desenvolvedor em algumas etapas.

Segue um link que encontrei falando sobre, para caso você queira mais informações:
https://www.devmedia.com.br/guia/jsf-javaserver-faces/38322